# In Javascript, does anonymous function keeps a strong reference to the object it contains?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, weak-references

Suppose a variable `foo` which contains an object, an anonymous function which returns it, and a WeakReference to `foo` exists:

```
let foo = { bar: 3 }

let af = function () {
    return foo
}

let ref = new WeakRef(foo)
```

Currently, `ref` is still refering to the object. And what I am going to do now is to set foo to `null` and forcibly invoke GC. (via running Chrome with --js-flags="--expose-gc" and using `window.gc()` method.):

```
foo = null
gc()
```

As a result, the object `{ bar: 3 }` was not GC'd. (Checked by calling `ref.deref()`) So, at first, I was convinced that anonymous functions hold strong references. However, I went [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef), and was able to find following:

> A `WeakRef` might never return `undefined` from `deref`, even if nothing strongly holds the target, because the garbage collector may never decide to reclaim the object.

Then I thought that garbage collector might have skipped to GC the object. So I did the same test on kotlin:

```
class Obj {}

var foo: Obj? = Obj()
val af = { foo }
val ref = WeakReference(foo)

foo = null
system.gc()
```

In kotlin, the object `Obj()` perfectly GC'd. But I am still uncertain, because the two languages are fundamentally different, and I have no idea whether Javascript engine surely had GC'd or not. I also tried using V8 runtime method (`%CollectGarbage(true);`) but still same.

So, in Javascript, does anonymous function keeps a strong reference to the object it contains?

Comment: `af` closes over `foo`, so `foo` won't be GC'd as long as `af` is referenceable

Comment: But if `af()` is *called* after `foo` is set to `null`, you should get `null` back.

Comment: Also, function `af()` doesn't *contain* the object. It contains code that references the variable `foo` in the outer scope. When `af()` is called, that reference will be resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood what I confused.